# jQuery: match currency with a regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

In the following:

`<span>This cost $15.99 per item</span>`

how do I return "$15.99" using jquery? The value can also be for example "$7".

Comment: @Amarghosh nice catch, but no need to worry about that case

Comment: to be more precise in the regex of your `.match(regex)` please read this http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-validate2.php see post under *currency*..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression would be something similar to `\$\d+(\.\d+)?` or `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to get rid of the sub group.

Comment: I did not down-vote it, but this would match two strings [0] = $15.99 and [1] = .99...

Comment: I hardly ever work with javascript regex and wasn't sure if it supported non-capturing groups so left it out, but a quick googling says it does support it so added a second version with that.

Comment: I was going to add the exact same answer as your second one with non-capturing groups. Good thing I didn't :) +1

Comment: @Reigel What's wrong with capturing the second part - use it if you want or else just ignore it.

Comment: @Amarghosh - yeah, nothing really... I was just thinking maybe that's the cause of the down-vote..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span").filter(function() {
    return this.text().match('\$\d+(\.\d+)?');
});
```

You can use just the match of `match('\$\d+(\.\d+)?')`, but the above function will filter spans that contain the match.

Comment: `match('\$[0-9\.]+')`, will also match `$15.99.99`

Answer (score 0):

Will the text always be "This cost [your price] per item", or is the text also arbitrary?

If the text is fixed, you can just `$.replace()` everything except the price (in two steps) with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
return($('span').text().match(/\$\d.+\d/));
```

[example](http://jsbin.com/uburi3)

Comment: This will match `$1asd3`, `$1 to $3`, `$1 and 2` and this won't match `$1` and `$12` - it needs part after $ to be at least 3 chars long

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xV97k/)

```
alert($('span').text().match(/\$\d+.\d+/));
```

but there is a code [here](http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-validate2.php) for the regex to be more precise...

Comment: Won't match `$7` as required in the question.

Comment: yes, it's not precise.. just like all the answers provided... I did post a link for more precise regex though....